# zipcmp in Synology NAS?

Tags: command-line, zip, synology

I want to compare a large zipped file in my Synology NAS to a copy of it I made that is on an external hard drive. I have heard zipcmp is good for this.  However, if I am downloading zipcmp or anything like it (sudo apt-get install zipcmp), do I have to get it from an SPK archive?  If zipcmp isn't in one, can I download it from anywhere else?

Finally, if zipcmp isn't possible within my Synology CLI (SSH), is there another tool anyone knows of that I can use to compare two large zipped files like this within a Synology NAS?

Thanks!

Comment: i think synology is debian based linux, as such one would use `apt` and/or `ipkg` and with `zipcmd` being part of `libzip-#.rpm` should be something that should be installable.

Comment: I don't think there's a synology package .spk to do what you describe, but if you ssh into the synology and get `apt` or `dpkg` of `ipkg` or whatever debian uses or simply get and manually install the libzip rpm I would think that would work; I'd almost be surprised if ssh command line didn't already have it being a basic zip library

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two large files you do not need to compare the files itself. You can create hash of the files. You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015085/2908599) for the steps how to login via shell in the NAS.

Depend of your desktop OS there are many tools to calculate hash.

Recommended algorithm is sha2 (sha256 for example)